# context_processor for tornado framework

Tags: python, tornado

How to implement context_processor or middleware for tornado python framework? I'd like to add common variable to base.html template. Without change all handlers bases classes.

Comment: You need to be more specific. You give no details on scope or structure. If all you want to do is make a variable accessible by everything you would just add a global variable.

Comment: I search not scecific solution :)
No, variable should be visible only for current request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler): 
    def render(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        kwargs['my_context_variable'] = 'context' 
        return super(MyHandler, self).render(*args, **kwargs)
```